# mkdir UTF-8 file name

Tags: php

I'm having some problem with `mkdir`

I'm using `xampp` on `windows`, when I try to create a `directory`, it returns not like should be, in example

```
mkdir(JPATH_SITE.'/images/projects/'.$region_folder.'/'.$project_folder, 0777, true);
```

Should return something like

```
/images/projects/Ленинградская_область/Ленинградская_область_1
```

But create a `directory` like:

```
/images/projects/Р›РµРЅРёРЅРіСЂР°РґСЃРєР°СЏ_РѕР±Р»Р°СЃС‚СЊ/Р›РµРЅРёРЅРіСЂР°РґСЃРєР°СЏ_РѕР±Р»Р°СЃС‚СЊ_1
```

It's something about encoding? or has to do with the OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows filenames are not encoded in utf8, but in `windows-1252` or `windows-1251` or smthing like that.

try this:

```
$dirname = JPATH_SITE.'/images/projects/'.$region_folder.'/'.$project_folder;
//replace "UTF-8" with the respective input charset, if it is not utf8
$dirname = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252",$dirname);
mkdir($dirname, 0777, true);

//if this doesnt work, try another charset like this:
$dirname = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1251",$dirname);

//you can also use iconv on your russian variables only
//remember that you might need to change UTF-8 to another input charset
$region_folder = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1251",$region_folder);
$project_folder = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1251",$project_folder);
```

read more about iconv here: [PHP iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

also useful to detect your charset encoding: [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Comment: Indeed, only with 
$region_folder = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1251",$region_folder);
$project_folder = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1251",$project_folder);
was enough! thank u